# Preprocess a buffer when opening and saving?

Tags: python, vim

Using vim, I would like to somehow have a piece of text that is always substituted with something else. Specifically, I would like `import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()` to appear as `PDB` and for `PDB` to be outputted as `import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()` when the buffer is saved.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly what you asked for, but you can use [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).

```
snippet PDB
  import pdb
  pdb.set_trace()
```

Then type `PDB<tab>`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a matter of appearance you could try something like

```
set conceallevel=2
syn region inPDB concealends matchgroup=bPBD start="import pdb ; " end="pdb\zs.set_trace()\ze"
hi inPDB gui=bold guifg=red
```

using [`syntax`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html) and its argument [`conceal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#conceal).